# Can we use the React Native component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

Recently I have a requirement where I need to use the react native component in react web app. I have searched and found one component i.e React Native Web.

That converts the react native component to work in react web app. Although I am having some errors but I actually wanted to confirm that whether it is doable to use the react native component in react web app SO that whenever we make changes in React Native Component, that will automatically be handled to be shown in the web. Because for react-native-web, we need to provide the react native file that will be converted into the web view. But how we can make sure that whenever we update the mobile component, changes will automatically be reflected on the web without making any changes.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yeah , U can use react-native-web.

But not all components working in react-native works on react-native-web , so u have to take care of those components and then u can maintain same codebase for both.

Further more, u can refer to https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web modules and components section